# Weird behavior with data.table and serialize

Tags: r, serialization, data.table

Here is a simple, reproducible example:

```
fobj1 <- function(a, b) {
  list(a)
}

make1 <- function() {
  data <- data.table::data.table(1:1e8)
  a <- 1; b <- 2
  fobj1(a, b)
}

tmp <- make1()
print(object.size(serialize(tmp, connection = NULL)), units = 'Kb')



fobj2 <- function(a, b) {
  f <- function() {NULL}
  list(a, b, 'f' = f)
}

make2 <- function() {
  data <- data.table::data.table(1:1e8)
  a <- 1; b <- 2
  fobj2(a, b)
}

tmp <- make2()
print(object.size(serialize(tmp, connection = NULL)), units = 'Kb')


fobj3 <- function(a, b) {
  f <- function() {NULL}
  list(a, 'f' = f)
}

make3 <- function() {
  data <- data.table::data.table(1:1e8)
  a <- 1; b <- 2
  fobj3(a, b)
}

tmp <- make3()
print(object.size(serialize(tmp, connection = NULL)), units = 'Kb')
```

If I source this, the outcome is:

```
0.1 Kb
22.6 Kb
390647.9 Kb
```

Apparently, `data` is taken somehow as a reference of the `list` in the last example. And the reason is that I haven't specified all the function arguments in the `list()`! Weird?!?

Can someone reproduce and explain?

`data.table` version: data.table_1.12.4

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: seems like it has something to do with the `refhook` argument in `serialize`. try `print(object.size(serialize(make3(), connection = NULL, refhook = function(e) "")), units = 'Kb')`. something to do with data.tables having external pointers and serialize pick that up to be stored. also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144239/how-to-use-saverds-refhook-parameter